# ST_3DClosestPoint for all Linestring Vertices and another Linestring

Tags: postgis

I want to get the closest point for each vertex of one linestring (table2) and another linestring (table1). So far, I have came up with the folowing query but it works only for one point and If i remove the limit 1 it gives me an error.

```
ST_3DClosestPoint( 
    (SELECT geom FROM table1 limit 1),
    (SELECT ST_PointN(geom, generate_series(1, ST_NPoints(geom))) FROM table2 limit 1)
    ),
    (SELECT ST_PointN(geom, generate_series(1, ST_NPoints(geom) )) FROM table2 limit 1)
)
```

Comment: do you need a generic multi row query (e.g. nearest neighbor) or are you only interested in doing that for one pair of lines? in your case above, use `(ST_DumpPoints(table2)).geom` instead.

Comment: First of all your SQL snippet is not valid/complete.  Second, what error do you get? Please edit the question, rather than replying in comment.s

Comment: @ThingumaBob I am looking to compare a pair of lines with multiple vertices